# How to use JSF(Primefaces) ajax Listener?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am having problem in using the ajax tag of the listener to invoke a method in the managed bean. The following code does not work. Although the ajax is invoking the JavaScript method `view.show()`, it does not invoke the managedbean method in the listener property.

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="customersFeedback"
  value="#{customersFeedbackController.allReadFeedbacks}"  
  widgetVar="reservationTable"
  selectionMode="single" 
  selection="#{customersFeedbackController.customersFeedback}" 
  rowKey="#{customersFeedback.id}">

   <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":viewFeedbackForm:viewDlg" listener="#
     {customersFeedbackController.setMessageAsRead()}" oncomplete="view.show()"/>
</p:dataTable>
```

Here is my managedbean. The update method is simply a method to update the CustomerFeedback object in the database.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "customersFeedbackController")
public class CustomersFeedbackController implements Controller<CustomersFeedback> {

    private CustomersFeedback customersFeedback = new CustomersFeedback();
    // other fields here

    @Override
    public void update() {
        customersFeedbackDao.update(customersFeedback);
    }

    public void setMessageAsRead() {
        customersFeedback.setStatus("Read");
        this.update();
        System.out.println("Method Executed"); // Just a test
    }

    // Other methods here

}
```

am I doing something wrong? If there is, feel free to correct me. Thanks.

Comment: you must pass an event parameter in your bean function, try doing that and let me know

Comment: @anas -that's not true; it's not mandatory to pass parameters in event listeners

Comment: @steven0529 - look in your browser's developer console for clues. There might be conversion/validation errors you're missing

Answer (score 1):

I observed that in your code for ajax you used

```
listener="#
     {customersFeedbackController.setMessageAsRead()}"
```

instead of this use following code:

```
listener="#
     {customersFeedbackController.setMessageAsRead}"
```

brackets are not needed to call function from backing bean.

also add `SelectEvent` to your backing bean method. like:
`public void setMessageAsRead(SelectEvent event){}`

refer: **http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajaxifyAction.jsf**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the datatable is inside a form in order to trigger the ajax event.